# Amazon S3 image name shows different filename or hash code while downloading instead of original file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi i am downloading the images stored in Amazon S3, but the downloaded names show some hash code. How to fix this situation?

Please help as i am new to AWS and not expert in the same how can i make changes so that it downloads the original file name

Comment: Are you using an AWS API to download an Amazon S3 object?

Answer (score 0):

In your download code functionality you should add

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="foo.bar"
```

Note Content-Disposition is case sensitive.